# every weakly compact set K in locally convex space E is metric space

Tags: functional-analysis

every weakly compact set K in locally convex space E is metrizable.

this is tru?

if not please give me an example.

Comment: You probably ask if $K$ is metrizable in the weak topology.

Comment: yes. every weakly compact set K in locally convex space E is metrizable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Let $X$ be a reflexive non-separable Banach space and denote by $X_{\leq 1}$ the closed unit ball of $X$.

By Banach-Alaoglu we know that $X_{\leq 1}$ is weakly compact. If $X_{\leq 1}$ is metrizable, then $X$ must be separable.

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/914570/regarding-metrizability-of-weak-weak-topology-and-separability-of-banach-spaces)  and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437746/reflexive-but-not-separable-space) for more on this.

Comment: thank you. for locally convex space with countable semi norm it is true?